# BigInteger as value holder in GWT model entities

Tags: gwt, biginteger, gwt-rpc

I'm using BigInteger in model classes just for storing and displaying values in most cases, without any math operations. The reason to do so (instead of using Strings) was to avoid conversion, since services I work with operate with BigIntegers. GWT implementation of BigInteger looks too heavy, so the question is whether it is reasonable to change properties with String types and do conversion on server side. Or it makes no difference since I do not operate with values on client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be prudent to go with BigInteger first. Only if there is a performance impact observed that can be traced back to BigInteger being in the pojo you need to think of alternate strategy. Do avoid micro-optimizing before hand.

Also ensure you are aware of BigInteger support in GWT and the bugs logged against the feature - http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/list?can=2&q=BIgInteger

Comment: Agreed - measure first, then cut. If the user is just typing in values, even a very slow parse is going to be fast enough to deal with it.